# Orthonormal system which is typically small on a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider real vector spaces $V_+$ and $V_-$, with $V:=V_+\oplus V_-\cong\mathbb{R}^n$, and say that $P_+$ is the orthogonal projector onto $V_+$, i.e. $P_+$ drops the $V_-$ components; resp. define $P_-$ w.r.t. $V_-$. Assume $n$ is large and $\dim V_+\approx\dim V_-$, or even that they are equal.

Let $\mathbb{1}/\sqrt{n}$ be the normalized all-ones vector and consider any orthonormal basis $v_1,\dots,v_n\in V$ where $v_1:=\mathbb{1}/\sqrt{n}$. Use the shorthand $v_i^\pm:=P_\pm v_i$. Then we know that $v_i^+\cdot v_j^++v_i^-\cdot v_j^-=0$ for $i\neq j$ while $\|v_i^+\|^2+\|v_i^-\|^2=1$.

Consider the multisets $S:=\{v_i^+\cdot v_j^+:1<i<j\}$ and $T:=\{\|v_i^+\|^2:i>1\}$, and let $S_\varepsilon:=\{x\in S:\lvert x\rvert\ge\varepsilon\}$ and $T_\varepsilon:=\{x\in T:\lvert x-\frac{1}{2}\rvert\ge\varepsilon\}$. That is, $S_\varepsilon$ and $T_\varepsilon$ track pairs which are "large" when restricted to $V_+$.

**What is known about $\#S_\varepsilon$ or $\#T_\varepsilon$?** I am particularly interested in upper bounds; bounds for specific $\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}$ are good too.

All I know so is that if $v_i^+\cdot v_j^+\in S_\varepsilon$ then $\|v_i^+\|^2,\|v_j^+\|^2\in\left[\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\varepsilon^2}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\varepsilon^2}}{2}\right]$ so in particular when $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, $\|v_i^+\|^2=\|v_j^+\|^2=\frac{1}{2}$, so this shows by Cauchy–Schwarz that $S_\varepsilon=\emptyset$ for $\varepsilon>\frac{1}{2}$.